# How to access another command within a sql command in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating a migration application to migrate data from one app to another.

```
using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(""))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from Client";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Client client = new Client();
                client.Active = reader["ActiveStatus"] == DBNull.Value ? false: Convert.ToBoolean(reader["ActiveStatus"]);
                client.Country = reader["Country"] == DBNull.Value ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["Country"]);
                client.Info = reader["Information"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)reader["Information"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above, I need to get `client.ProductId` from another table using the `Id`. How can I create another query inside the above to get the data? Should I add a new command?

Comment: whats the relationship between `Client` table and the "another" table? Why not use `Joins` and fetch the whole thing once instead of hitting the database repeatedly?

Comment: Please add both SQL tables so we can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data using inner join from Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935928/get-data-using-inner-join-from-dapper)

Comment: Assuming you would like to perform two separate calls you could perform two select operations in scope of one Command and return DataSet of two tables with SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: You can create a class including a function that calls a single SQL value `scalar` then call it via code

`public class Class1
{
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString");
    private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    private object obj;
    public object GetCell(string strsql)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        con.Open();
        obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar;
        con.Close();
        return obj;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

use ***JOIN*** between two tables instead of multiple sql command. ***JOIN*** would be much faster and easier. Better use this. [For Reference](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-inner-join.php)

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Cl.ProductId,
                           Pr.ProductId,
                           Cl.ActiveStatus,
                           Cl.Country,
                           Cl.Information
                   from Client cl 
                   [INNER/LEFT/RIGHT] JOIN Product Pr 
                   on Cl.ProductId = Pr.ProductId";
```